# How to do date subraction of date condering only weekdays when there are null values?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have to calculate the date difference between 2 dates fields in a dataframe. I have to follow the below conditions  while doing the calculation.

```
  1) Include only count working days doing subraction i.e exclude saturday and sunday while doing the calculations.
  2) If Date 1 is null populate the difference as Null
  3)If Date 2 is null populate the difference as Null

**Sample Data**
Date1                  Date2
1/10/2019 17:24   15/2/2019 17:41
8/1/2019 12:04    11/1/2019 10:02
                  16/1/2019 11:30
21/1/2019 16:30  
23/1/2019 20:35  30/1/2019 12:35

7/1/2019 17:58   8/1/2019 14:18
24/1/2019 11:50  25/1/2019 8:00
                 1/3/2019 13:00
7/1/2019 12:55   8/1/2019 15:03
```

I tried with  below code

```
 data['date_diff'] = ((pd.to_datetime(data['date2']) -  pd.to_datetime(data['date1'])) .dt
```

But breaks whenthere is null value.How to fix this

Comment: Why don't you use `np.where` to populate with Nulls?

Comment: If your nulls are defined as `numpy.datetime64('NaT')` then the subtraction will also return a `NaT`.

Comment: What do you mean with "count weekday"? The difference in amount of weeks?

Comment: @Erfan Isn't it just the number of weekdays? i.e, Friday this week to Monday next week would be 1 weekday.

Comment: @Erfan, I dont want count weekend days between the dayes. I.e exclude saturday and sunday while counting difference.

Comment: @rpanai, My date field is string  so i converted it to datetime and then doing the transformations. It breaking when there is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure there is some more elegant way but you can consider to play from this

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date1 = "1/10/2019 17:24,8/1/2019 12:04,,21/1/2019 16:30, 23/1/2019 20:35,,7/1/2019 17:58,24/1/2019 11:50,,7/1/2019 12:55"
date2 = "15/2/2019 17:41,11/1/2019 10:02,16/1/2019 11:30,,30/1/2019 12:35,,8/1/2019 14:18,25/1/2019 8:00,1/3/2019 13:00,8/1/2019 15:03"
df = pd.DataFrame({"date1":date1.split(','),
                   "date2":date2.split(',')})

for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

def fun(row):
    if row.isnull().any():
        return np.nan
    ts = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(row["date1"],row["date2"]), columns=["date"])
    ts["dow"] = ts["date"].dt.weekday
    return (ts["dow"]<5).sum()

df["diff"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis=1)
```

Comment: I have exact the sameuse case and this doesn't work for all rows. It returns Null value even if there valid value date field

Comment: @ashokeapen is the type for your columns `datetime64[ns]`? Do you mind to run `for i, row in df.iterrows(): print(row,fun(row))` and tell me for which dates you get `NaN`?

Comment: my columns are` datetime64[ns]`. I am getting an error when i run code you mentioned. It says `name 'fun' is not defined`

Comment: You need to run the cell containing `def fun...` first